# insert an element at end node of link list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

i want to add a node at end of link list. so i made a method for the same and it gives expected result. But i am not sure about this program is correct or not. please see program wether it is correct or not.

```
node *insert_end_node(node *nd, int value) {
  node *tmp, *p;

  tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node *));

  tmp->data = value;
  tmp->next = NULL;
  p = nd;
  while (p->next != NULL) {
    p = p->next;
  }

  p->next = tmp;

  // nd =tmp;

  return nd;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: for point 1 , i know it that it has to check wether the list is empty. but my confusion is that when i nd  assign to p and check that so p has also hold the base addres of list. and go to the last node where p->next == null because need to add another node at end node. so my question is that these below code :

  p->next = tmp;
   nd = p;// confusion 
  return nd; //so i got the unexpected result 

but code is given below code 

  p->next = tmp;
  
 return nd ; // so i got the expected result

why need not nd=p is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. When you accept a pointer as a parameter, you should always check to see if it is NULL. In your case, if `nd == NULL`, then you will try to access `NULL->next` and your program will likely crash.
2. When you call `tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node*))`, you want to allocate enough memory for a *node*, not for a node pointer. The correct code is `tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node))`. An even better option is to write `tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(*tmp))`, because if you decide to change `tmp`'s type, the allocation will still work.

Comment: Also, since malloc returns void* there is no need to cast it to a node* (in C)